# nftables map `port` to `ip:port` for DNAT

Tags: linux, nftables

Is it possible to have an nftables map which maps `port` to `ipv4_addr:port`, where `port` and `ipv4_addr:port` have different TCP port numbers? For example, I want to dnat all incoming packets on port 80 to a container running a web server on port 8080 (purely with nftables). This is possible using two maps and two map lookups, as below:

```
table ip dnatTable {
  chain dnatChain {
    type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
    dnat to tcp dport map { 80 : 172.17.0.3 }:tcp dport map { 80 : 8080 }
  }
}
```

However, I was wondering if it is possible with only a single map lookup?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual *nftables* is a moving target. This feature appeared in [***nftables* 0.9.4** released on 2020-04-01](https://lwn.net/Articles/816528/):

> - NAT mappings with concatenations. This allows you to specify the address and port to be used in the NAT mangling from maps, eg.
>
>   ```
>   nft add rule ip nat pre dnat ip addr . port to ip saddr map { 1.1.1.1 : 2.2.2.2 . 30 }
>   ```
>
>   You can also use this new feature with named sets:
>
>   ```
>   nft add map ip nat destinations { type ipv4_addr . inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service \; }
>   nft add rule ip nat pre dnat ip addr . port to ip saddr . tcp dport map @destinations
>   ```

So in OP's case that would be:

```
nft add ip dnatTable dnatChain 'dnat ip addr . port to tcp dport map { 80 : 172.17.0.3 . 8080 }'
```

Just for information, [*nftables* 1.0.0 released on 2021-08-19](https://lwn.net/Articles/866923/) has a simplified syntax:

> - Simplify syntax for NAT mappings. You can specify an IP range:
>
> [...]
>
> Or a specific IP and port.
>
> ```
> ... dnat to ip saddr map { 10.141.11.4 : 192.168.2.3 . 80 }
> ```

So OP's case can then be shortened to (and previous rule will be displayed as):

```
nft add ip dnatTable dnatChain 'dnat to tcp dport map { 80 : 172.17.0.3 . 8080 }'
```

---

Using a named map can help to separate rules from data. This would work too instead (using 0.9.4 syntax):

```
nft add map ip dnatTable portToIpPort '{ type inet_service : ipv4_addr . inet_service ; }'
nft add rule ip dnatTable dnatChain dnat ip addr . port to tcp dport map @portToIpPort
```

and then at any convenient time:

```
nft add element ip dnatTable portToIpPort '{ 80 : 172.17.0.3 . 8080 }'
```

Comment: Just to make sure, what is the exact syntax for the simplified command? It says `dnat to ip saddr map { 10.141.11.4 : 192.168.2.3 . 80 }`. Does that mean it maps the source IP to the combination of `daddr:dport`? So if I wanted to map dports to the same thing I'd have to replace `ip saddr` with `tcp dport` and adjust the map accodringly?

Comment: @Lithimlin Use the complete syntax version: i your nftables version supports it, it will display back the simplified version. The kernel side receives exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: @Lithimlin Beside what you want to do was exactly what OP wanted to do: it's in the answer already.